# Python requests - not able to get fresh response each time from CGI script

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python script that gets name popularity data from https://www.ssa.gov/OACT/babynames/index.html. There's a CGI script `/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi` that returns the output in table format, based on two request parameters, `year` (or `yob`) and `top` (top 10, 20 etc.). I need to be able to aggregate results for different years by passing request URLs for different years but with the same `top` value, say, `10`. But the page does not refresh for different request URLs, e.g. the response pages for `https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi?yob=2000&top=10` and `https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi?yob=2004&top=10` are the same.

```
>>> QUERY_URL = 'https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi'
>>> results_page_04 = requests.get(QUERY_URL, params={'year': 2004, 'top': 10}, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no
 ...: -store, must-revalidate'}).text
>>> results_page_00 = requests.get(QUERY_URL, params={'year': 2000, 'top': 10}, headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no
 ...: -store, must-revalidate'}).text
```

These two responses are exactly the same, and the responses are actually for the year 2015, which is strange.

Is there some header I have to set before sending off the request (I'm using the `requests` library).

Answer (score 0):

That site uses `post` not `get` parameters to search. Page 2015 is displayed when you forgot query params.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi'

for year in range(2000, 2016):
    data = {'year': year, 'number': 'p', 'top': '10'}

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)

    if response.ok:
        print(response.text)
```

Dev tools in browsers are your friend, you can get everything you need by examining network tab.